# Series Approximation How to evaluate $1/3+1/3(1/3)^3+1/5(1/3)^5+...$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation

How to evaluate $$\frac13+\frac13(\frac13)^3+\frac15(\frac13)^5+...$$?

I faced this particular sum in the website www.toppr.com .And it is given under the heading "Problems on Approximation"...but I cant figure out a method.How to approach?Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n-1}\Big(\frac13\Big)^{2n-1}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\Big(\frac13\Big)^{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n}\Big(\frac13\Big)^{2n}\\
&=-\log(1-\frac13)+\frac12\log(1-\frac19)\\
&=\frac12 \log2
\end{align}
where we use $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}x^{n}=-\log(1-x)$.

Comment: Alternatively, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n+1} x^{2n+1}=\text{arctanh }x$.

Answer (score 2):

The given series is $x+\frac {x^3} 3 + \frac {x^5} 5 + \dots \big|_{x = \frac 1 3} \\
              = \frac 1 2 \log \frac {1+x} {1-x} \big|_{x = \frac 1 3} \\
              = \frac 1 2  \log 2 .$